# Как запустить скрипт ещё раз?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть вот такой скрипт

```
<script>
                function lol() {
                    var secs = sessionStorage.getItem('secs') || 11;
                    var timer = setInterval(function () {
                        secs--;
                        var element = document.getElementById("status");
                        element.innerHTML = "<h2>У вас осталось <b>" + secs + "</b> секунд до закрытия вопроса</h2>";
                        if (secs == 0) {
                            sessionStorage.removeItem('secs');
                            document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').click();
                            clearInterval(timer);
                        }
                        else {
                            sessionStorage.setItem('secs', secs);
                        }
                        if (secs == 0) {
                            clearInterval(timer);
                        }
                    }, 1000)
                }
</script>
```

Как сделать чтобы после того, как этот скрипт отработал, запустился ещё раз?

ТОЛЬКО ПОСЛЕ ТОГО КАК ОТРАБОТАЛ

Answer (score 0):

```
function lol() {
  var secs = sessionStorage.getItem('secs') || 11;
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
     secs--;
     var element = document.getElementById("status");
     element.innerHTML = "<h2>У вас осталось <b>" + secs + "</b> секунд до закрытия вопроса</h2>";
     if (secs == 0) {
       sessionStorage.removeItem('secs');
       document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').click(); // - ???
       clearInterval(timer);
       lol(); // !!!
     } else {
       sessionStorage.setItem('secs', secs);
     }
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное, пробовал всякие сложные конструкции, а до такого простого не додумался)))

Comment: этот код нажимает на кнопку, а как сделать, если пользователь нажал на кнопку чтобы скрипт сбрасывался?

Comment: @ПинчукСергей Вынести декларацию `var timer` из функции наружу, и по нажатию на кнопку вызывать `clearInterval(timer);`.